# Braces in FOR type loop, has changed result of code unexpectedly

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JS. In book is exercise to make code by using `for` keyword instead of `while`. `While` is always "original example". All kind of examples will be using loops.

This example will print `#` sign into lines to look like triangle:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######  
#######  
########  
#########  
##########
```

**[code #1]** Used `while`:

```
var line = "";
var counter = 0;
while (counter < 10) {
    line = line + "#";
    print(line);
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```

**[code #2]** Same, using `for`:

```
var line = "";
for (var counter = 0; counter < 10; counter = counter + 1) {
  line = line + "#";
  print(line);
}
```

In both cases are used braces.

In other example I will raise 2 to the power of 10.
**[code #3]** By `while`:

```
var result = 1;
var counter = 0;
while (counter < 10) {
  result = result * 2;
  counter = counter + 1;
}
show(result);
```

**[code #4]** And same by `for`:

```
var result = 1;
for (var counter = 0; counter < 10; counter = counter + 1)
  result = result * 2;
show(result);
```

- Why braces are not used in [code #4] and it is working well without them ?
- Why [code #2] prints just last line of triangle (##########), when I don't use braces ? When I use braces, it will print whole triangle, as we need.

Comment: // since I havent 10 reputation points, I can post max two links and cannot post images.  Here is second part of my question.//   http://prntscr.com/1ltren  
So I have used it as this: http://prntscr.com/1ltrok  
but it printed just last line of triangle.  
Then I tried to put braces in there like this: http://prntscr.com/1lts0m  
and it worked.  

I would like to get explained why in one case braces were not needed for correct result, but in other case they are needed.  
Thanks.

Comment: It is much better to put the raw text into the question rather than screen shots (helps with searching and permanence of the question).  I've done the first two, you can do the rest.

Comment: this website formattings is pretty hard to use/learn. I was trying but I wont spend whole day with it, I have more important things to do, though. Sorry. I'm not arrogant, but I'm really not comfortable with it :(

Comment: You put the code in place, select the code, and hit the `{}` icon (from left to right - `B` bold, `I` italics, link, `"` block quote, and `{}` code).  This will format the code into a perforated text block that will be highlighted according to the tags of the question.  Please remember that we are volunteers here too and transcribing images isn't fun for me either (I have more important things to do too).

Comment: You can look at the two examples that I've done to see how to do it yourself.  Alternatively, you can just put four spaces in front of each line of code (thats what the `{}` button does).

Comment: ok, pls dont delete your comments, will look into it tommorow. now I have to leave from pc. thanks

Comment: If you don't use braces then only the one line directly following the `for` or `while` (same for `if` btw) statement will be repeated (`triangle = triangle + "#"` in your case and the print command would be 'behind' the loop). Many people would claim that omitting the braces is bad style and prone to errors anyway so just use them all the time.

Comment: So how does that for-loop look like? It can't be that hard to edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

**Always use braces.**

When you dont use braces, JS engine automatically *glues* next statement after `for` to complement it, so the code on listing #2 essentially becomes:

```
var line = "";
for (var counter = 0; counter < 10; counter = counter + 1) {
  line = line + "#";
}
print(line);
```

and prints only last line.

*Same behaviour is specified for `if`, `else` and `while`, also.*

Comment: Not "next line", but next *statement*. It could be on the same line, or there could be multiple statements in the next line.

Comment: because `;` separates statements.

Comment: c69 you used word ' to complement it' by which do you mean as synonim for 'addition' ?

That is isn't a part of body of loop, right ?

Why it can't be all in same line line:

for (var line = ""; var counter = 0; counter < 10; counter = counter + 1; line = line + "#";)

How may I enter my lines to be seen in other line ?  shift+enter doesn't work for outcome.  And how may I put inside of comment block of code (to be seen not as regular text). I really don't like commenting stuff. It is very confusing and annoying.

Comment: offtopic: _you cannot enter multi-line comments on stackoverflow._ "Complement" here is more a synonym of "auto-complete", "be the natural second part", hopefully that is undertandable.

Comment: Why it can't be all in same line line: for (var line = ""; var counter = 0; counter < 10; counter = counter + 1; line = line + "#";)

Comment: because `for` uses semicolons for slightly different purpose, and its only allowed to have exactly 2 of them inside the braces http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Traditional_for_loops